# Android: inflate layout multiple times causes performance issues

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a Horizontal scrollview in a fragment of which I am inflating the same layout multiple times (i.e. about 300) in a loop on ActivityCreated method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i++) {

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().(R.layout.item, null);
        parentLayout.addView(view, params);
    }
}
```

I have noticed some performance issues on inflation on this loop, i.e. there is a delay before the fragment is shown.

Not sure what the best approach to tackle this, and what is the best process for inflating multiple layouts in a loop?

If I could do it asynchronously, that might be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is precisely the situation for which you should be using an [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). In this case, a ListView is probably the best fit. It does a lot of smart things such as only creating views when the will be visible and recycling views as they scroll out of visibility.

Comment: Yes, but I need horizontal scroll capability along with the fact my horizontal scrollview is within a vertical scrollview

Comment: In the case where you want horizontal scrolling, A ViewPager is the best fit. If you're dead set on something directly analogous to a ListView, there are several HorizontalListView implementations on GitHub. In either case, creating a view for every data item and putting them all in a horizontal scrollview is the wrong thing to do.